# how to display a GridView using javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have `GridView1` in which I have added extra column called Details, and each row is the Grid  has a link button called Details. I have written a javascript that fetches a column value.

Therefore what I want to do is I need to use that value as key to display details fetching from the database. I want to present those details in the form of Grid.

The asp.net code and the script I have written is :

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details">
<ItemTemplate>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Click for more details" onclick="OpenPopup('<%# Eval("Device_Profile_Name") %>')">
Details</a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Device_Profile_Name" HeaderText="Device_Profile_Name"
SortExpression="Device_Profile_Name" ReadOnly="true" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Node_Profile" HeaderText="Node_Profile" SortExpression="Node_Profile" />
</Columns>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function OpenPopup(dev_pro_name) {
        alert("Device_Profile_Name: " + dev_pro_name);
        /*window.open("dummyPage.aspx?autoid=" + Device_Profile_Name, "", "width=300,height=200");*/
    }
</script>
```

Kindly help..Thank you..!!

Comment: Does it have to be using Javascript? Maybe you can use a Master-Detail Views with the ASP.NET Ajax Library http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335720.aspx

Comment: Its Ajax, I dunno anything about it. And looking at the link which you have given seems very scary to understand and implement.

Comment: There's no quick trick to do it. Just follow the steps in the link above and check out the code sample attached to the article and you'll find it simple enough.